# Can't combineLatest using router state in Angular

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm trying to use combineLatest from Ngrx to perform an action on navigation end, or state change in another subscription. In my component's `ngOnInit()`, I have:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const routerSub = this.router.events.subscribe();
    const patientSub = this.patientService.state.subscribe();

    Observable.combineLatest(routerSub, patientSub, (routerEvent, patientState) => {
      console.log(routerEvent);
      console.log(patientState);
    });
  }
```

However, I have a compiler error on `routerSub`:

> Argument of type 'Subscription' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'IScheduler | Subscribable | PromiseLike | ArrayLike |
>   ((...values: any[]) => {})'

What am I supposed to be providing to `combineLatest` for the router state?

Comment: also take a look at [Learn to combine RxJs sequences with super intuitive interactive diagrams](https://blog.angularindepth.com/learn-to-combine-rxjs-sequences-with-super-intuitive-interactive-diagrams-20fce8e6511)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) combines `observables` and emits the latest values when all of the observables have a latest value to emit. So you need to pass in observables, not subscriptions. So your code should be changed to

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const routerSub = this.router.events;
    const patientSub = this.patientService.state;

    Observable.combineLatest(routerSub, patientSub, (routerEvent, patientState) => {
      console.log(routerEvent);
      console.log(patientState);
    })
    .subscribe();

}
```

Comment: Ah - I was also missing the final `.subscribe()`. If I follow the example at: https://netbasal.com/rxjs-six-operators-that-you-must-know-5ed3b6e238a0 however, I never see any values emitted. I know state is populated, as there are other components that leverage `patientState` that are working correctly. Only after navigating do I see the values emitted. I was expecting to see the latest `patientState` whether I navigated or not.

Comment: @Brandon combineLatest does not fire an initial emit when you first subscribe. So you won't get the latest values until one of the observables emits.

Comment: Hmm. Is there another operator that will? or a better methodology?

Comment: @Brandon sorry I was mistaken. the combineLatest `will` emit on subscribe `if` both observables have a latest value to emit. So it sounds like what is happening is your state does have a latest value, but router.events does not. This is why when you navigate, now both observables have a latest value and combineLatest emits. So you are looking for something that emits on subscribe if either observable has a latest value and then emits if either observable emits?

Comment: @Brandon from your OP, it sounds like you want the [merge](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/merge.html) operator. It takes multiple observable sequences and combines them into one. So after you subscribe if either the state changes or a navigation happens merge emits a value.

Comment: I actually ended up using `race`. I'm marking your answer as accepted because it *did* solve my compilation question :)

Comment: @Brandon glad i could help!